# Korean cosmetic-sample - what is it?

Tags: translation

dear ones,

I got this little cosmetic-sample, and have problem to translate it...  What is it?
Can somebody help me, please?

Best regards, xoxo: Sophie [image: TonyMolly sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is product by brand calls `"TonyMoly"` and it is: `Floria Brightening Foam Cleanser`

(Grapefruit extract to create clear and bright skin.
)

[Link to read about product](https://tonymoly.us/products/clean-dew-foam-cleanser?variant=645680791568) (choose the Grapefruit one to more information...)

**BTW** you can translate image here: https://translate.yandex.com/ocr